React Native Calendar picker doesn't show dates changes
I am using react-native-calendar-picker in my app and I have a weird problem. The date in the state updates onDateChange, but the calendar doesn't show it in the view. I need to go to next month, then back and it shows the last chosen date as active. All the code is on Snack
But for the first look, I will also post the code
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import CalendarPicker from 'react-native-calendar-picker';

const CalendarScreen: React.FC = () => {
    const [selectedStartDate, setSelectedStartDate] = useState<Date>(new Date());
    const startDate = selectedStartDate ? selectedStartDate.toLocaleDateString() : '';

    const onDateChange = (date: Date) => {
        setSelectedStartDate(date)
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <CalendarPicker 
                startFromMonday={true}
                selectedDayColor="#97D7ED"
                todayBackgroundColor="#CBEBF6"
                months={['Styczeń', 'Luty', 'Marzec', 'Kwiecień', 'Maj', 'Czerwiec', 'Lipiec', 'Sierpień', 'Wrzesień', 'Październik', 'Listopad', 'Grudzień']} 
                weekdays={['Pon', 'Wt', 'Śro', 'Czw', 'Pt', 'Sob', 'Nd']}
                previousTitle="Poprzedni"
                nextTitle="Następny"
                onDateChange={onDateChange}
            />
            <Text>Wybrana data: {startDate}</Text>
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        padding: 15,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    }
})

export default CalendarScreen;

